# Issue on showing a modal using vue js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3

I have some problem on how to display a bootstrap modal using `vue.js` and `laravel 5.3`. I just added the `vue model` inside `blade.php` but modal seems no working. Please see sample code below:

html:

```
<div id="project">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="showModal = true"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add new</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade in"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Project</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Project Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="date" name="date"  class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Project Date">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="category"  class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Project Category">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <textarea name="desc" id="inputDesc" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="dropzone"  id="project-thumbnail">
                      </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

script:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#project',
    data: {
            showModal: false
    }
})
```

Comment: You are toggling showModal but where is it being used to actually open the modal?

Comment: @DavidK.Hess, yes it should open a modal on click event using vue.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `show` class and `v-if="showModal"` to your modal:

```
<div class="modal fade in show"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" v-if="showModal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

Build something cool!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code to trigger it. If you aren't use bootstrap's `data-modal` then you need to use the Javascript API to open it documented here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript

I.e. you need a method on your Vue that calls:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Yeah, I can show the bootstrap modal using its default attributes, but how can we open it using vue?

Comment: Isn't that the whole gist of my answer? You have to call Javascript from a Vue `method`.

Comment: @David K. Hess, Maybe you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451971/how-can-i-display-modal-in-modal-on-vue-component